# How to insert 3 values to a button and recover separately afterwards in onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to put 3 values in my button
that I could in an onClick
retrieve them separately to modify three 3 states at a time
how to do ?

I tried to put them as an object
however it considers everything as a 'string'

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


  this.state= {
    one = null,
    two = null,
    three = null

   }


keep = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value ) // (value1)(value2)(value3)
    console.log(e.target.value.value1) // (value1)
      console.log(e.target.value.value2) // (value2)
        console.log(e.target.value.value3) // (value3)
 this.setState({
     one : value1
     two :  value2
     three : value3
 })

}


    
   <button onClik={this.keep}
     value={(value1),(value2),(value3)}>
    click me </button>
```

Comment: Does this work at all as it seems this is not even in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need them in value you can take them as an argument to your function as I did below

```
keep = (value1, value2, value3) => {
    console.log(value1) // (value1)
      console.log(value2) // (value2)
        console.log(value3) // (value3)
 this.setState({
     one : value1
     two :  value2
     three : value3
 })

}



   <button onClik={() => this.keep(value1, value2, value3)}
     value={yourValue}>
    click me </button>
```

Comment: interesting but in the situation of an array map, I will not know the values ... unless we can give them a generic name?

Comment: Can explain it in more detail, so that I can help you

Comment: In fact it's perfect that's exactly what I wanted to do thank you man !!! good

Answer (score 1):

Pass it inside the click handler function as params would be fine.

Try the in-text demo:

#### Classical

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      one: null,
      two: null,
      three: null
    };
  }
  clickHandler = (a, b, c) => e => {
    this.setState({ one: a, two: b, three: c }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler("A", "B", "C")}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

#### Functional

```js
const App = () => {
  const clickHandler = (a, b, c) => e => {
    console.log(a, b, c);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickHandler("A", "B", "C")}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```